# Fluent NHibernate, questions about code design

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Greeetings, i'm a new to Fluent NHibernate.

Let's imagine, a have a lot of classes

ClassA
ClassB
ClassC
...

After creating schema, i want to get a list of created tables.

For example:

Opening form -> there's a names of the Tables, when we clicking to each one we're getting records from this table.

How can I achieve this? Is there a cheaper way? 
Is it possible to make without reflection? *(Parsing all classes, and gettings it's names)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHiberante has built-in support to get names of all mapped entities and their tables. The code could look like this:

```
ISessionFactory factory = ... // get your NH ISessionFactory;

// all mapped entities as dictionary
var allClassMetadata = factory.GetAllClassMetadata();

foreach (var meta in allClassMetadata)
{
    var persister = meta.Value as NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister;
    var tableName = persister.TableName;
    var entityName = persister.EntityType.Name;
    ... 
    // TODO what needed with this info
}
```